# Using TorchScript classes as members in pytorch modules

Tags: python, pytorch, torchscript

I'm trying to make some existing pytorch models support the TorchScript jit compiler, but I'm running into issues with members that are of non-primitive types.

This small example illustrates the issue:

```py
import torch

@torch.jit.script
class Factory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create(self, x: float) -> torch.Tensor:
        return torch.tensor([x])

class Foo(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.factory: Factory = Factory()

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.factory.create(0)

mod = torch.jit.script(Foo())
```

When ran, the jit compiler gives the error

```
RuntimeError:
module has no attribute 'factory':
at example.py:17:15
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.factory.create(0)
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
```

I've tested that the `Factory` class is available to the jit inside the `forward` method, but it does not acknowledge it when I store it as a member. Why is this? And is there any way I can get the jit compiler to save this kind of members into the compiled module?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in PyTorch which was resolved soon after you posted your question: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/jit-scripted-attributes-inside-module/60645, https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27495.

Updating PyTorch should fix it.

Comment: Oh hi there Ray.

Comment: @rocksNwaves Top 'o the mornin' to ye.